# zsh で補完を定義するには？

Tags: zsh

zsh にはあまり詳しくないです。

`foo □` と入力した後に、(□はカーソル) TAB を入力した際には、 `bar` もしくは `piyo` を補完したいです。
これは、どうやったら実現できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のファイルを_fooという名前で$fpath（環境変数）が通っているところ作成します：

```
#compdef foo
_foo () {
  _value mode_name bar piyo
}
```

$fpathが定義されていないかシステムのものしかない場合は自身でzshrc内で定義するよいいでしょう。
より詳細な情報は`zsh compdef`でググると出てくるでしょう。例えば以下が詳しいとおもいます。
https://gist.github.com/mitukiii/4954559

また既存のコマンドの補完がなくて困っているなら[zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions)をインストールすると良いでしょう。